# Service Account authentication to upload a file to Google Drive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api

I need to upload a file to Google Drive from my Web Application. I need to use Service Account authentication. I have read Google Drive guide here: [DotNetQuickStart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet) and this tutorial for authentication [Authentication Google Drive MVC](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/#OAuth2_Authentication) but i don't know what i need to do.

In order to Google Drive guide i have set the parameter to Google Developers Page.

I have download and implemented secret.json file to my project and i have add this code to my project:

```
public static Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File uploadFile(string _uploadFile, string _parent)
    {
        string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }; // Full access

        var keyFilePath = @"c:\file.p12";    // Downloaded from https://console.developers.google.com
        var serviceAccountEmail = "xx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";  // found https://console.developers.google.com

        //loading the Key file
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = scopes
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

But i can't understand what to set in keyFilePath and serviceAccountEmail. How can i set this code?Thanks to all

Comment: Open the secret jSon file see if they are in that I cant remember other wise they should be on your project on Google Developers console.  As far as I know the Google .Net client library still doesn't support it.  I should look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the P12 key file instead of secret.json

Go to https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts --> select your project --> click on the 3 vertical dots located at the right side of the listed Service account --> Create key --> you will see the below dialog

[image]